# How to check if a record has already been created today

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

Once the main form is loaded, I want Access to check to see if a record has already been submitted today. If so, I want that tab to be invisible.

However, using the code below, I receive "Data type mismatch in criteria expression." (Runtime error '3464')

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
   Set db = CurrentDb
   Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblCalibration", dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)

   rs.FindLast "CalibrationDate='" & Date & "'"

   If rs.NoMatch Then
      navCalibration.Visible = True
   Else
      navCalibration.Visible = False
   End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would get that error if your *CalibrationDate* field is Date/Time datatype.  In that case, enclose the value of `Date` in `#` rather than `'` characters.

```vb
'rs.FindLast "CalibrationDate='" & Date & "'"
rs.FindLast "CalibrationDate=#" & Date & "#"
```

Additionally you could format the `Date` value in order to avoid any possible confusion between *d/m/yyyy* and *m/d/yyyy* formatted dates.

```vb
rs.FindLast "CalibrationDate=" & Format(Date, "\#yyyy-m-d\#")
```

However it should be simpler to just use the `Date` function's name and not be bothered about formatting.

```vb
rs.FindLast "CalibrationDate=Date()"
```

Still simpler, use `DCount()` to count the number of rows where *CalibrationDate* contains today's date.  You wouldn't need to bother with the recordset using this approach.

```vb
If DCount("*", "tblCalibration", "CalibrationDate=Date()") = 0 Then
    Me.navCalibration.Visible = True
Else
    Me.navCalibration.Visible = False
End If
```